# R add a class to a field

Tags: r, types, r-s4

I've created two classes in R:

```
library(methods)

Foo <- setClass(
    # Set the name for the class
    "Foo",

    # Define the slots
    slots = c(
              # THIS IS PROBABLY WRONG
              bar = "S4"
            ),
    )
```

And

```
Bar <- setClass(
    # Set the name for the class
    "Bar",

    # Define the slots
    slots = c(
            a = "character"
            ),

    # Set the default values for the slots. (optional)
    prototype=list(
            a = "qwerty"
            ),
    )
```

I want to say something along the lines of `Foo.bar <- Bar()`. I think that should be done something like this:

```
# create a method to assign the value of a coordinate
setGeneric(name="addBar",
                       def=function(theObject)
                       {
                               standardGeneric("addBar")
                       }
                       )

setMethod(f="addBar",
                      signature="Foo",
                      definition=function(theObject)
                      {
                              theObject@bar<- Bar
                      }
                      )
```

I then call this using:

```
if (!interactive()) {
    result <- tryCatch({
           foo <- Foo()
           foo <- addBar(Foo)
        }
        ,

        warning = function(war) {
            print('A warning occurred')
            print(war)
        },

        error = function(err){
            print('An error occurred')
            print(err)
        }
        )
    print(result)
}
```

However, if I run this I'm greeted with:

> assignment of an object of class “Bar” is not valid for @‘bar’ in an object of class “Foo”; is(value, "S4") is not TRUE>

However, when I print the type of Bar, I get S4. I've tried multiple different types but I'm fresh out of ideas.

How do I assign a class object to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class of `Foo@bar` should be probably `Bar`, and you should define the class `Bar` first:

```
Bar <- setClass("Bar",
    slots = c(a = "character"),
    prototype=list(a = "qwerty")
    )


Foo <- setClass("Foo", 
    slots = c(bar = "Bar")
    )
```

Please note that once you have created `foo <- Foo()`, the `bar` slot of `Foo` *will* be already initialized (try `str(foo)`, so I think that you don't need the `addBar` generic. Unless it is supposed to do something else then what you describe.

Also, if anything, then you should define your method as follows:

```
setMethod(f="addBar", signature="Foo",
          definition=function(theObject) {
            theObject@bar<- Bar()
           })
```

(assuming that all you want is to initialize the `@bar` slot with an empty `Bar()` object). If you do `theObject@bar <- Bar` then you assign the class generator function `Bar` to the slot `@bar` and will get an error:

```
Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass)  : 
  assignment of an object of class “classGeneratorFunction” is not 
  valid for @‘bar’ in an object of class “Foo”; is(value, "Bar") is not TRUE
```

Finally, note that the call

```
foo <- addBar(Foo)
```

does not do what you think it does. `Foo` is a function used to generate new objects of class `foo`. So `addBar(Foo)` tries to run an `addBar` method on an object of class `classGeneratorFunction`, which is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I'm new to R and really struggling. My specific intent is to import a class object from another file (bar) and make my variable of that object type in my original class (foo). You say I first have to define bar before defining foo, so does  this mean my intent is impossible?

Comment: What do you mean by "another file"? Also, does that mean that Bar is already defined elsewhere? Then you don't need to define Bar at all. Maybe you should be more specific in your question as to what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have two files. In my first file, I have Foo. Foo imports the file that has Bar defined and creates a variable bar. My goal is to copy a dynamic import functionality from python.

Comment: I strongly suggest to describe this idea in more detail a new question on its own. Unless I am very mistaken, the dynamic import functionality from Python is more or less the default in R. What is that you cannot do in R that you would need to implement new classes for? I am not trying to say that there is no such thing, but just that maybe you are trying to do things in R the Python way while they can be more easily achieved the R way.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the line

```
bar = "S4"
```

To

```
bar = "Bar"
```

This seems to solve the problem.